# Use my word_counts.txt to generate image captions

Tags: tensorflow

Use my word_counts.txt to generate image captions.

Here's my error code:

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
File "/root/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 85, in 
     tf.app.run ()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
     _sys.exit (main (_sys.argv [: 1] + flags_passthrough))
   File "/root/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 55, in main
     vocab = vocabulary.Vocabulary (FLAGS.vocab_file)
   File "/root/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_utils/vocabulary.py", line 49, in init
     reverse_vocab = [line.split () [0] for line in reverse_vocab]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide some code. Read how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is happening because one of your lines is empty and split () returns []